# Is this verb tense correct?: She is going to teach the extra parts THAT he didn't tell you

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

> She is gonna teach the extra parts **that** he didn't tell you

I've been googling with this over an hour; `verb tense rules after the word "that" in a sentence` but couldn't find any of related results or useful informations.

Can I start my sentence with verb tense `didn't` after the word **`that`**? And where can I find rest of the rules that **verb tenses after** **`that`**?

This makes chocking me. Please help me.

Comment: You may be looking for rules that didn't exist, that he didn't tell you about, and that will not show up later.

Comment: Hello, stackedbook. If you don't mind, I'll choose another (similar) example, one with less informal English. _She is going to buy you the other parts of the set, the parts that **you couldn't afford**._  // A famous one is _This is the house that **Jack built**._  You could have _This is the house that **Jack bought us**._ Which is more like your sentence.  'That' is often called a _relativiser_ nowadays, though many books use the term _relative pronoun_. You'll see that the parts in bold print use noun plus past tense verb. But ...

Comment: it doesn't need to be past tense; it could be present, or a future construction. Please don't be offended, but this is really a question more suitable for the ELL site, and you may well be transferred there.

Comment: that he didn't tell you *about*.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So you mean people don't say like the example what I've written? I feel I lost now.

Comment: Sorry if I didn't help. I'm glad Lambie could.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

She's going to teach the extra parts that he didn't tell you *about*.

to *tell someone about* something.

We leave the **about** in order **to avoid: about which he didn't tell you.**

When English calls for prepositions followed by which and other wh-words, we leave the preposition in spoken language.

*say something about something:*

Those are the ones he said nothing **about.**

That is another example.

Any tense can be used after that, depending on what is in the first clause.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the sentence, but is that the verb tense `didn't` after that acceptable?

Comment: @stackedbook There is no tense issue here. :) There is no rule for  tenses after that. Tenses depend on the whole context and any tense can come after "that".

Comment: Oh cool then :> My struggle is gone now. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You don't really need the *tell you* at the end:

> She is gonna teach you the extra parts that he didn't.

or

> She is gonna teach the extra parts that he didn't.

Or you could add "mention" or "point out" or "touch on" at the end of my example.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question which was asking about verb tenses.

Comment: Fair. I don't know the answer to that and don't have enough reputation to simply comment.

Comment: There are no rules about verb tenses that apply to _that_ clauses, so it's not surprising they were hard to find. In a _that_ clause, you have to use either present or past, but you can use either one and you can use more than one tense if the clause is complex. Tense has nothing to do with constructions unless it's an idiom. This isn't an idiom.

Comment: Hello, Julien. You may prefer our sister site, ELL, aimed at more basic English.